# Probability of 2 consecutive heads in 5 tosses of a fair coin

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm somehow getting the answer 1. Total number of possible events is $2^5$.

Now the number of favorable events:

2 consecutive heads can happen in following ways:
$$H\: H\: (H\:or \: T)\:\:(H\:or \: T)\:\:(H\:or \: T)$$ $$ (H\:or \: T)\:H\: H\:(H\:or \: T)\:(H\:or \: T)$$$$ (H\:or \: T)\:(H\:or \: T)\:H\: H\:(H\:or \: T)$$$$ (H\:or \: T)\:(H\:or \: T)\:(H\:or \: T)\:H\: H\:$$

Each of these $4$ possibilities can happen in $2^3$ ways corresponding to whether it's H or T in the remaining 3 tosses.

So, favorable number of events = $4\cdot 2^3$

Probability$=\frac{4\cdot 2^3}{2^5}=1$

What did I miss?

Comment: Exactly two or at least two ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only ways to *not* get two consecutive heads are
$$\sf TTTTT\\ TTTTH, TTTHT, TTHTT, THTTT, HTTTT\\ TTHTH, THTTH,HTTTH, THTHT, HTTHT, HTHTT\\ HTHTH$$

So the probability you seek is $1-13/2^5$.

That is $19/32$, or $0.59375$

---

The trouble with your method is the massive overcounting of common outcomes.

$$\require{cancel}\sf \phantom{[}H\phantom{\vert T]~[}H\phantom{\vert T]}~[H\cancel{\vert T}]~[H\vert T]~[H\vert T] \\ [H\cancel{\vert T}]~\phantom{[}H\phantom{\vert T]~[}H\phantom{\vert T]}~[H\vert T]~[H\vert T]$$

Answer (score 4):

The possibilities you mention aren't mutually exclusive so you cannot just add them. $HHHHHH$ is in all of them e.g.

It might be easier to count the unfavorable ones instead?

Comment: How do I count the disfavorable ones?

Comment: FInd all those where every head is followed by a tail.

Answer (score 2):

When you throw the coin five times and get five times head, it involves 2 consecutive heads.

When you throw the coin five times and get four times head, it involves 5 ways you can obtain 2 consecutive heads.

When you throw the coin five times and get three times head, it involves $\binom{5}{3}-1$ ways with 2 consecuitive heads, since the only possible way you do not end up with the desired constallation is $HZHZH$

When you throw the coin five times and get two times head, there are 4 ways to arrange them.

That means there are $1+5+9+4=19$ combinations with two consecutive heads.